# Why the fonts and spaces of my SVG image edited by browser?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm integrating psd mock-ups in HTML and CSS. In these mock-ups there are SVG images (especially the logo) that I have to integrate in navbar. The problem is the following: when I link the SVG logo in the HTML, the browser edits its font and spacings.

I tried to link the PNG version, it works: no edits are made. But, the logo is blurry, this is not the result I want to have.

Then I tried to integrate the SVG image with the `<svg>` tag but I don't understand how it works, the image doesn't appear at all.

Here you can find with my 3 attempts:

```
<div>
     <!--With svg-->
     <a href="index.html"><img src="http://54.38.187.146/visa-en-ligne/images/logotest.svg" class="top-navbar-logo"></a>

     <!--With png-->
     <a href="index.html"><img src="http://54.38.187.146/visa-en-ligne/images/logotest.png" class="top-navbar-logo"></a>

     <!--Tried this below but doesn't work-->
     <svg viewBox="0 0 16 16">
         <use xlink:href="http://54.38.187.146/visa-en-ligne/images/logotest.svg" ></use>
     </svg>            
 </div>
```

My jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/HeloiseC/fpsqhkc8/1/

Actual result (1st attempt in code): SVG logo's font and spacings are edited. Below a screenshot.

[image: actual_result]

Expected result: include the SVG (and not the PNG) logo without it being edited by the browser. I would like the image to be the original one (it looks like below).

[image: expected_result]

Comment: Depends whether the browser can find the font SegoeUIBlack

Comment: one solution would be using a `<tspan>` for the .com: `<text y="34.98" class="st0 st1 st2">aa ligne<tspan class="st3">.com</tspan>`

Comment: Tell the designer creating the svg's that he needs to change the inline text to paths or else you need to provide the explicit font if it's not available (not advised) to retain the intended result. If he's using an editor like Adobe Illustrator it's as simple as just selecting the text, right clicking, and choose "Create Outlines" and it does it for ya. Then wherever/however you use the image it will look as it's intended. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the comments.
@RobertLongson I have a CSS file where I declare this font (with @font-face) and even if I do `.top-navbar-logo{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI Black', sans-serif;
}`, it doesn't work.

Comment: @enxaneta this would mean to write the text in HTML, I just would like to integrate the .svg.

Comment: @ChrisW., yes I guess vectorizing is the best solution to do. But if you or someone knows why the browser doesn't recognize the font and how to force it to do so, I am interested, why do you think it is not advised to provide the font?

Comment: I see no @font-face in the SVG file and anyway you can't have external references in an SVG file when it's used as an image so the font would need to be defined as a data-url in the SVG file.

Comment: @HéloïseChauvel This is not HTML is SVG. Please replace your two text elements with `<text y="34.98" class="st0 st1 st2">aa ligne<tspan class="st3">.com</tspan>`